# ContextMenu in ASPxHtmlEditor

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, devexpress

I am developing asp.net project in c#.In my application i use Devexpress htmleditors and i need custom conetxtmenu . So i tried to add conextmenu item from code behind but i got following errors.

1.DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.ASPxHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems' is inaccessible due to its protection level

2.The property or indexer 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.ASPxHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible

And this wht i tried in code behind.

```
htmlEdtBody.ContextMenuItems.Insert(0, new HtmlEditorContextMenuItem("Add Title...", "AddTitle"));
```

Anyone one knows what is the reason for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through ASPxHtmlEditor's demo - [Features - Context Menu](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxhtmleditordemos/Features/ContextMenu.aspx), there is a nice demo, that help you understand how this will work.

Firstly set the [ASPxHtmlEditorSettings.AllowContextMenu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxHtmlEditorASPxHtmlEditorSettings_AllowContextMenutopic.aspx) property. You may have to [ASPxClientHtmlEditor.ContextMenuShowing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxHtmlEditorScriptsASPxClientHtmlEditor_ContextMenuShowingtopic.aspx) event.
[ASP.NET HTML Editor Control](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/DXv2/index.xml?page=53)

Refer - [Context Menu](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7531)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (!IsPostBack) {
          MyHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems.CreateDefaultItems();
          MyHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems.Insert(0, new HtmlEditorContextMenuItem("Add Title...", "AddTitle"));
          MyHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems.Insert(1, new HtmlEditorContextMenuItem("Change Title...", "ChangeTitle"));
          MyHtmlEditor.ContextMenuItems.Insert(2, new HtmlEditorContextMenuItem("Remove Title", "RemoveTitle"));
     }
}
```

this - [ASPxGridView - Editing using popup menu and ContextMenu event](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q268658.aspx)  may help you..

Comment: thank you. i think issues in my dlls. i used DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v11.1.dll . But in demo , they use DevExpress.Web.ASPxHtmlEditor.v12.1.dll . I think issues is in there.